# How to define command / variable for vscode terminal?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm not really sure what terminology I should use for this, but for example, to run a Java application on vscode, I can press ctrl + F5 and the terminal will print out

```
& 'C:\Users\UserName\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.25.1\scripts\launcher.bat' 

'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.7.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' 

'-cp' 'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\project folder' 'Main'
```

Is there a way to define a variable like

```
String java = & 'C:\Users\CIQBILLY\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.25.1\scripts\launcher.bat' 

'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.7.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe' 

'-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp'
```

so that I can just type

```
java 'path' 'Main'
```

to run a program?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can. You need to use alias. Or, you can use `code-runner` extension for one click operation

Answer (score 0):

no, you cann't, because the terminal cann't get the value which you had defined, and the debug extension will dynamically change the port of the server, so, even you copy the commands you had used, it willn't work any more, you can try it. so, let the extension do the things what is belongs to it.